# expectation of the stopping time

Tags: probability-theory

> Let $\mathbb{P}(X_k = 1) = \mathbb{P}(X_k = -1) = \frac{1}{2}$, for $k\in \mathbb N$  and $$\tau = \inf{ \{ n \ge 1 : S_n = X_1+\cdots + X_n \ge 2\}}$$ For $p \in (0,1)$ find $\mathbb{E}p^\tau$.

Is there any "algorithm" how to deal with such problems? I know, that if I want to find $\mathbb{E}(\tau)$, I can take $S_n^2 - nVarS_n$ as a martingale and by OST I get this $\mathbb{E}(\tau)$ eventually (I know that it doesn't have to work, but it's just an example). But what about $\mathbb{E}(\phi(\tau))$? I'm supposed to guess what martingale should I use or there is some other way?

Comment: $Εp^τ$ is the probability generating function of the random variable $τ$.

Comment: The usual approach is first to note that $\tau=\sigma+\sigma'$ where $\sigma$ is the first hitting time of $1$ and $\sigma'$ is the first hitting time of $2$ starting from $1$ hence $\sigma$ and $\sigma'$ are i.i.d. and $E(p^\tau)=E(p^\sigma)^2$. Second, after one step, either one is at $1$ and then $\sigma=1$, or one is at $-1$ and then $\sigma=1+\tau'$ where $\tau'$ is distributed as $\tau$. Thus, $E(p^\sigma)=\frac12p+\frac12pE(p^\sigma)^2$, which yields $E(p^\sigma)=p^{-1}(1-\sqrt{1-p^2})$. (As an aside, note that $E(\tau)=E(\sigma)=\infty$ hence the approach you ...

Comment: ... underline to compute $E(\tau)$ seems doomed from the start.)